# Primefaces SelectBooleanCheckbox gets unchecked on form submission

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am new to this Website My issue is related to SelectBooleanCheckbox in primefaces.
Whenever I submit my form, the checkbox gets unchecked.
I am using dynamic tabview.

Here is my xhtml code:-

```
<h:form id="form" >
<p:panel id="tagsPanel" >
<p:tabView id="tabView"  style="background-color:transparent;background-image:none;" var="tabKey" value="#{MBean.Names}"  
      dynamic="true"  >
<p:dataGrid var="appSettingsList"  value="#{appSettingsMBean.tabData[tabKey]}"    columns="1" styleClass="plainDataGrid">
    <h:panelGrid columns="2"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  columnClasses="JspContent12 ,JspContent22"  width="100%" >
         <p:column escape="false" >  
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{appSettingsList.resultValues.checkboxValue}"   style="float:left" id="checkBoxValue"
                     rendered="#{appSettingsList.currentValues != null and appSettingsList.currentValues.size() > 0 and
                      appSettingsList.displayType.equalsIgnoreCase('single') and appSettingsList.dataType.equalsIgnoreCase('boolean')}">
                     </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
           </p:column>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dataGrid>   
</p:panel>
          <p:panel border="0" id="buttonRow" style="text-align:center;border-width:0;border-style:none;background-image:none;" >           

        <p:commandButton  value="Save"   id="save"  actionListener="#{MBean.saveSettings()}" ajax="false" style="width:130px" />
</p:panel>
</h:form>
```

The checkboxes remain checked when tabs are changed and save btn is clicked
But,when only the save btn is clicked,it gets unchecked
Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please use MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve when asking a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here,

```
<p:commandButton ... ajax="false" />
```

Ajax is turned off. Thus a **full page refresh** is performed after submitting the form. That the checkbox got unchecked suggests that the bean doesn't properly keep its state, or that you're performing business logic in a getter method, which causes it to return a fresh new model everytime instead of the one holding the submitted values.

You've 2 options:

1. Just use ajax. I.e. get rid of `ajax="false"`. If you intend to update certain parts of the view on submit, then just specify `update` attribute accordingly.
2. Make sure that your bean doesn't mess with the state or getters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @BalusC,But,i have not messed with the getters.
Also,the state of the checkbox remains when I just change and click **Submit** the tab without any other action

Comment: It only becomes null on **Form** sunmission with no action.
Can it be due to the TabView  dynamic = **true**